# Validate reference in Firestore Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to whenever someone adds a document, validate if a key is present which holds a value of a `reference` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#references) in Firestore Security Rules. I can do this already with any native Javascript type (`request.resource.data.something is string`). I was wondering something like that is possible with `references`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `resource.Foo is path`.
Note that null doesn't pass this check. I typically use `(resource.Foo is path) || (resource.Foo == null)`.